# Reorder an array in python

Tags: python

I want to sort an array, so it starts off at

```
order = [0,1,2,3,4,5]  #loop around trying all columns`
```

and then will go through, trying all combinations of this so 1,2,3,4,5,0 etc, and stop once it has tried all of them.

Is there anyway to do this in python?

Comment: `order.sort()`  works..

Comment: Do you want all the `rotations` or all the `permutations`?

Comment: Do you want to produce all possible permutations or you want to find A particular one and stop the search there?

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to "rotate" a list, have a look at the [`deque`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#deque-objects) class:

```
>>> from collections import deque
>>> order = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
>>> order.sort() # ensure order is sorted
>>> q = deque(order)
>>> for _ in xrange(len(q)):
...   q.rotate(-1)
...   print q
...
deque([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0])
deque([2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1])
deque([3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2])
deque([4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3])
deque([5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
deque([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you mean *all* permutations, rather than the rotations in Dominic's answer:

```
import itertools

permutations = [ p for p in itertools.permutations(order) ]
```

There's 720 permutations in total so I won't print them :)

Comment: `[p for p in <iterable>] <==> list(<iterable>)` Converting an iterator to a list can be very expensive, especially for permutations, which would consume O(n!) memory. Yikes.

Comment: Sure, depending on what he wants to do with the permutations, he may not need them stored in a list. In which case much better to iterate over itertools.permutations(order) directly. Good point!